# $9\{x\}=2x+[x]$, how many values of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**:

> How many values of $x$ will satisfy the equation $9\{x\}=2x+[x]$, where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

**My attempt**:

> We have $3$ cases: $x\in Z, x\in (R^+-Z^+), x\in (R^--Z^-)$.
> Case $1$: $x\in Z$
> $\{x\}=0$, $[x]=x$ 
> $\Rightarrow x=0$
>
> Case $2$: $x\in (R^+-Z^+)$
> $[x]=x-\{x\}$ 
> $\Rightarrow 9\{x\}=2x+x-\{x\}$
> $\Rightarrow 10\{x\}=3x$
>
> Case $3$: $x\in (R^--Z^-)$
> $[x]=x-\{x\}-1$ 
> $\Rightarrow 9\{x\}=2x+x-\{x\}-1$
> $\Rightarrow 10\{x\}=3x-1$

The **answer given** to the question **is** $\bf3$.
But I'm not getting that. Please help.

Comment: Note that $0≤\{x\}<1$ so $0≤9\{x\}<9$, so there aren't a whole lot of cases to try.

Comment: Notation:  It's more usual these days to use $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to denote the floor (because the ceiling function is just as natural).  That's realized as \lfloor x \rfloor

Comment: @lulu maybe that's why question has defined it. Though I agree with you.

Comment: That was certainly the old notation, but the new one is better.

Comment: @lulu since I'm having $10\{x\}$ then I won't be having any solution from Case 1 and Case 2 so I'll get just 1 answer which will be again wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote.  The equation is $9\{x\}=x+\lfloor x \rfloor$ which is equivalent to $8x=10\lfloor x\rfloor$.  There are only a few values to check.

Comment: Should say:   I do not agree with the official answer.  I see four solutions, namely $\{0, \frac 54,\frac 52,\frac {15}4\}$

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor = x -\{x\}-1$ is wrong.

Comment: @jjagmath why? $-10 = -9.3 +0.3 -1$ That's how I verified

Comment: $\{-9.3\}=.7$ not $.3$

Comment: @lulu you have calculated using the wrong equation, its not $9\{x\}=x+[x]$ it is instead $9\{x\}=\bf{2}$ $x+[x]$

Comment: @InanimateBeing  Oh, right.  Thank you. In that case we get $9x-9\lfloor x\rfloor = 2x+\lfloor x \rfloor \implies 7x=10\lfloor x \rfloor$  which does indeed have three solutions, namely $\{0, \frac {10}7, \frac {20}7\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x\in\Bbb{R}$,we know
$x=\{x\}+\lfloor x \rfloor$$ \ \text{ and }
\ 0\le \{x\}<1$

---

$$9\{x\}=2x+\lfloor x \rfloor$$

$\Rightarrow 9\{x\}=2\{x\}+ 2\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor$

$\Rightarrow 7\{x\}=3\lfloor x \rfloor$

$\Rightarrow \{x\}=\frac{3}{7}\lfloor x \rfloor$

Hence $0\le \frac{3}{7}\lfloor x \rfloor<1$

$\Rightarrow 0\le \lfloor x \rfloor< \frac{7}{3}$

So possible solutions are $\lfloor x \rfloor =0, 1,2$ and corresponding fractional parts are $\{x\}=0, \frac{3}{7}, \frac{6}{7}$

Hence possible solutions are $x=0, \frac{10}{7}, \frac{20}{7}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Got it. +1. Nicely explained.

Comment: Whenever I was making edit, you were making too, so before I could submit, you corrected all the minute errors. Now I don't see any errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=n+q, n \in I, q\in [0,1)$
Then the eq becomes
$9q=2n+2q+n$ so $0<q=3n/7 <1$ are the  possible values of n are 0,1,2.
The corresponding of q are $0, 3/7, 6/7$. Finally, $x=0, 10/7,20/7$ are the solution of the given eq.